# Sequence - NO CACHE vs CACHE 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

Is there any difference between a `SEQUENCE` declared using `NO CACHE` and one declared using `CACHE 1` in SQL Server 2012+?

Sequence #1:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.MySeqCache1
AS INT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9999
    NO CYCLE
    CACHE 1;
GO
```

Sequence #2:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.MySeqNoCache
AS INT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9999
    NO CYCLE
    NO CACHE;
GO
```

Is there any difference between the two? Will they behave differently when being used in a SQL Server 2012+ environment?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is hard to give a definitive answer on this question until you actually find a difference. I have found none but that does not mean there is no difference only that I have not seen one in the tests I have made.

The easy test is for performance. Either getting the next value in a loop or using a numbers table as a source to generate multiple values at a time. In my tests there were no difference in performance between using no cache and a cache of 1 value but there was a significant performance improvement of using a cache of 2.

This is the code I used to test performance:

```sql
declare @D datetime = getdate();

declare @I int = 0;
while @I < 9999
  select @I = next value for dbo.S;

select datediff(millisecond, @D, getdate());
```

Result:

```
Cache        Time(ms)
------------ --------
NO CACHE     1200
1            1200
2             600
1000           70
```

To dig a bit deeper I used the extended events `sqlserver.metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence` and `sqlserver.lock_acquired` to see if there was something different in how the values persists to the system table.

I used this code to test for no cache and cache size of 1 and 4.

```
DECLARE @S NVARCHAR(max) = '
CREATE EVENT SESSION SeqCache ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_acquired(
    WHERE (sqlserver.session_id=({SESSIONID}))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence(
    WHERE (sqlserver.session_id=({SESSIONID}))) 
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N''d:\SeqCache'');';

SET @S = REPLACE(@S, '{SESSIONID}', CAST(@@SPID AS NVARCHAR(max)));

EXEC (@S);

GO

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.S
AS INT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9999
    NO CYCLE
    NO CACHE;
--    CACHE 1;
--    CACHE 4;

GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION SeqCache ON SERVER STATE = START;

GO

DECLARE @I INT = 0;
WHILE @I < 10
  SELECT @I = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.S;

GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION SeqCache ON SERVER STATE = STOP;
DROP EVENT SESSION SeqCache ON SERVER;
DROP SEQUENCE dbo.S;
```

There is no difference in output for using no cache and cache of 1.

Sample output:

```
name                                      persisted_value mode
----------------------------------------- --------------- -----
lock_acquired                             NULL            SCH_S
lock_acquired                             NULL            IX
lock_acquired                             NULL            U
metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence  1               NULL
lock_acquired                             NULL            SCH_S
lock_acquired                             NULL            IX
lock_acquired                             NULL            U
metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence  2               NULL
lock_acquired                             NULL            SCH_S
lock_acquired                             NULL            IX
lock_acquired                             NULL            U
metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence  3               NULL
```

When using a cache of 4.

```
name                                      persisted_value mode
----------------------------------------- --------------- -----
lock_acquired                             NULL            SCH_S
lock_acquired                             NULL            IX
lock_acquired                             NULL            U
metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence  4               NULL
lock_acquired                             NULL            SCH_S
lock_acquired                             NULL            SCH_S
lock_acquired                             NULL            SCH_S
lock_acquired                             NULL            SCH_S
lock_acquired                             NULL            IX
lock_acquired                             NULL            U
metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence  8               NULL
```

The `SCH_S` lock is done when a value is needed. And when the cache is exhausted it is followed by a `IX` and the a `U` lock and finally the event `metadata_persist_last_value_for_sequence` is fired.

So there should be no difference between using no cache and and cache 1 when it comes to potentially losing values on an unexpected shutdown of SQL Server.

Finally I noticed something in the Message tab in SSMS when creating a sequence with cache 1.

> The cache size for sequence object 'dbo.S' has been set to NO CACHE.

So, SQL Server thinks there is no difference and tells me so. There is however a difference in `sys.sequences` in the column `cache_size`. It is NULL for no cache and 1 for a cache of 1.